# How to process CSV files with unknown token length

Tags: scala, hadoop, cascading, scalding

I am writing a Scalding job to transform data in the following format:

```
Id,Name,Param1,Val1,Param2,Val2....ParamxValx
1,Cat,Hair,White,Eye,Blue...
```

Into:

```
Id,Name,Param,Val
1,Cat,Hair,White
1,Cat,Eye,Blue
```

My problem is that I don't know how many Param/Val items might be present in a given line. I do know that they are CSV though. How can I write a Scalding/MR job to transform my data?

Everything I have read recommends doing the following:

`Csv("data.csv", "," , ('productID,'price,'quantity)).read`

but in that case I would need to know the "schema" of my CSV file, which I don't, given that there may be arbitrarily many Param/Val entries per line.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  There must be some kind of schema, even if that schema has a varying number of columns.  If you were to read the file by hand would you be able to understand it?

Comment: Don't read the file as CSV. Read it as TSV (basically single field) and in the code split it based on `,`. Do rest of the operations based on tokens generated.